# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

Tags: node.js

I have run the server and getting an error as:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Queue instance at:
    at RedisClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Vs Code Folders\Feelare\node_modules\kue\lib\redis.js:65:13)
    at RedisClient.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at RedisClient.on_error (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Vs Code Folders\Feelare\node_modules\redis\index.js:401:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Vs Code Folders\Feelare\node_modules\redis\index.js:279:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
```

My Code is as:

```
const env = require('./environment');

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${env.db}`);

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "Error connecting to MongoDB"));


db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connected to Database :: MongoDB');
});


module.exports = db;
```

I have tried by installing redis and adding it into script but error is same.And also tried in production and development environment but the error is same.

Comment: Have you tried using `mongodb://[::1]/${env.db}`?

Comment: Is your redis server running? From the error message & port you are trying to connect to a redis server.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be with redis server. Try running `redis-server` in the terminal.
Hope this helps!

[image]